# CURL isn't running from Crontab

Tags: cron, curl

[image]

Here is the output. Not sure if cron isn't running or other issue. If I issue `curl --silent http://..../scanner.php` from terminal, I'm getting desired output. Actually scanner.php do some check and send an email. I've getting that. But not working from cron. Can you please advice me how can I detect the issue?

**Edit:** I have fixed the issue by adding a space before "&" and a new line after the command. Thanks all.

Thanks

Comment: You miss a space before the ampersand. Check crond is running too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in your logs in `/var/log`.  If you grep them for CRON you should find messages from it, it normally logs successes and failures.

```
grep CRON /var/log/*
```

At a guess I'd ask whether your crontab file has a newline at the end.  Without one the whole file normally fails.

> cron  requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline
>   character. If the last entry in a crontab is missing a newline (ie,
>   terminated by EOF), cron will consider the crontab (at least
>   partially) broken. A warning will be written to syslog.

Comment: The output of `crontab -l` clearly indicates that he has a LF sign at the end of line.

Answer (score -1):

try wget using the following pattern

```
*/10 * * * * wget http:link.com/
```